# Analytical Continuation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, branch-cuts

I have problem understanding the analytical continuation of the following complex integral. I even have the solution but can not figure out the intermediate steps. I would appreciate it if anyone could explain the steps from left to  right. I guess it is related to the branch cuts where my knowledge is  limited.
$$
\frac{1}{i}\int_{\epsilon-i\infty}^{\epsilon+i\infty} dt \frac{\exp\left( a t \right)}{\sin^{2\mu} \left( \pi t \right)}= \int_{0}^{\infty} dx \frac{\exp\left( i a x - i \pi  \mu \right)}{\sinh^{ 2 \mu} \left( \pi x \right)} + \mbox{C.C.}
$$

Thank you!

Comment: Could you post the steps that confuse you?

Comment: I do not understand how the factor $ \exp\left(- i \pi \mu \right)$ appears in the numerator.

Comment: Note that $\sin{(\pi \mu x)} = i \sinh{\pi \mu x)}$, and that $$i^{2 \mu} - (-i)^{2 \mu} = e^{i \pi \mu} - e^{-i \pi \mu}$$

Comment: Thanks Ron, I followed your hint and got

Comment: $$
\frac{1}{i}\int_{\epsilon-i\infty}^{\epsilon+i\infty} dt \frac{\exp\left( a t \right)}{\sin^{2\mu} \left( \pi t \right)}=
$$
then $t=ix$
$$
=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \frac{\exp\left(  i a x \right)}{ i^{2\mu} \sinh^{2\mu} \left( \pi x \right)}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dx \frac{\exp\left(  i a x- i\pi \mu \right)}{  \sinh^{2\mu} \left( \pi x \right)}\\
=\int_{0}^{+\infty} dx \frac{\exp\left(  i a x- i\pi \mu \right)}{  \sinh^{2\mu} \left( \pi x \right)}+\int_{0}^{+\infty} dx \frac{\exp\left( - i a x- i\pi \mu \right)}{ (-1)^{2\mu} \sinh^{2\mu} \left( \pi x \right)}
$$

Comment: I am not sure if I did it correctly as I do not arrive at the solution above.

Comment: I think it is more complicated than a simple substitution.  The $\epsilon$ in there means that you are integrating away from the imaginary axis - it looks like an inverse Laplace transform, and these are usually computed using Cauchy's theorem and defining an appropriate contour.  Check that solution to see what I mean - or just post it, or a link and I can take a look.

Comment: @RonGordon, Sorry, I did not understand your last line: "or just post it, or a link and I can take a look". Do you mean I start a new question? Thanks.